# Inconsistent Helix3 behavior using megamenu and multiple columns

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, helix3, jmenu

I have 2 sites:

- ariesagro.in
- agswitches.in

Both are using Joomla and the latest version of Hexil3, but I am getting different results.

I am not able to activate megamenu in agswitches.in where in ariesagro.in it's working fine.

I am not able to create multiple columns in single row in agswitches.in, where in ariesagro.in I can.

Can anyone tell me how to make Helix3 work consistently on both sites?

Comment: Welcome to JSE. As this is a template specific issue, I'm going to  suggest you contact the developer of the template on their website: https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/index

Comment: We not only want to help you, we want to help countless researchers in the future.  As your question is currently written it would be nearly impossible for a researcher to know if their issue is the same as your issue because you have not isolated any possible contributing factors.  Volunteers have no way of reproducing your issue and therefore could only venture to m ake blind guesses.  This makes your question Unclear.  Please edit to make your question clearer and more valuable.